# Interpolating a function of two variables

Tags: functions, interpolation

I am trying to create the interpolating function for a function of two variables, over a finite area. Just for consistency we can think of a function:

```
MyFunc[a_,b_]:=Sin[a*b]/Sqrt[1+a^2+b^2]
```

I've read the documentation and, in order to get the interpolating function I use:

```
MyTable=Table[MyFunc[a,b],{a, -5, 5, 0.1}, {b, -5, 5, 0.1}]
MyApproximateFunc = ListInterpolation[MyTable]
```

this seem to work, but when I try to plot MyFunc and MyApproximateFunc they look very different: I must have missed some detail...

```
Plot3D[MyFunc[a, b], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}]
Plot3D[MyApproximateFunc[a, b], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}]
```

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: its because your MyTable does not know about the corresponding values of a and b; try MyTable = 
  Table[{a, b, MyFunc[a, b]}, {a, -5, 5, 0.1}, {b, -5, 5, 0.1}] // 
   Flatten[#, 1] &;

MyApproximateFunc = Interpolation[MyTable]

Comment: If you read the docs, notice that `ListInterpolation[]` supports a domain specification; try `MyApproximateFunc = ListInterpolation[MyTable, {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]`.

Comment: chris: works like a charm! Too bad it's only a comment and I can't accept it... :-)

Comment: @zakk you can always upvote my comment ;-)

Comment: C'mon @chris move your comment to an answer, I promise I won't tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK then after Sjoerd C. de Vries request ;-), you can either use (less thinking)

```
MyTable = Table[{a, b, MyFunc[a, b]}, {a, -5, 5, 0.1}, {b, -5, 5, 0.1}] // Flatten[#, 1] &; 
MyApproximateFunc = Interpolation[MyTable];
```

or (from @J.M.'s comment, less memory)

```
 MyTable = Table[MyFunc[a, b], {a, -5, 5, 0.1}, {b, -5, 5, 0.1}] // Flatten[#, 1] &; 
 MyApproximateFunc = ListInterpolation[MyTable, {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}];
```

to get

```
  GraphicsRow[{Plot3D[MyFunc[a, b], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}],
               Plot3D[MyApproximateFunc[a, b], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is `FunctionInterpolation`. Straight from the Documentation:

```
   MyApproximateFunc = 
    FunctionInterpolation[
     Evaluate[Table[D[MyFunc[a, b], {{a, b}, k}], {k, 0, 2}]], {a, -5, 
      5}, {b, -5, 5}]
```

We have to provide derivatives to get a better interpolation.

```
GraphicsRow[{Plot3D[MyFunc[a, b], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}], 
  Plot3D[MyApproximateFunc[a, b], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Markus.Roellig ah! I *knew* that there was a way to tell interpolation to use the derivative as well. Thanks for the tip!