# How to perform multi-variate Interpolation from discrete data in a text file

Tags: interpolation

I have a table of data of 4 columns in text file.

x y z w

This is basically $(x,y,z)\rightarrow w$.
How can I use an interpolation function in *Mathematica* to figure out an equation $f$ of 3 variables that tries to approximate the data?

I read the answers posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14157/interpolating-a-function-of-two-variables), but they were using `Table`, and I am not sure how to put my data into the right format for *Mathematica*.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "do I can hardcode into a mathematica file." The function you'll need to use is still [`Interpolation`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0ldf0pe-hvle88), as in the linked question, so given that you know the approach already, I think the question is just about how to load your data. You don't give any detail on what format you currently have the data in, but please look up [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) in the documentation. Please also clarify your question to indicate what part of the process you are having trouble with.

Comment: Question has been edited to a clear form and an answer has been provided. I don't think this question should be closed.

Comment: @rhermans the (undocumented) `Interpolation[{{x1, y1, z1, w1}, {x2, y2, z2, w2}, ...}]` from the other question would have worked fine; it does not need to be the structure you show in your answer. This was not what was unclear about the question. The unclear aspect was, given that OP obviously *already knows* how to interpolate the data because they refer to a working solution in the question, what actually are they asking? Similarly, I have no confidence that your edit assuming that the problem is something to do with `Interpolation` actually captured OP's intended meaning.

Comment: omega, could you please tell us whether or not the edit to your question was correct and whether the answer solves your problem?

Comment: @OleksqndrR I rather use the documented form, less ambiguous and allows `GatherBy` the Abscissa.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) expects multivariate data in the format

```
{
 {{x1,y1,z1}, f1},
 {{x2,y2,z2}, f2},
 {{x3,y3,z3}, f3}
}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you will need to first import the data

```
data = Import[filepath, "Table"]
```

then format it in the right way

```
Map[{Most[#], Last[#]} &, data]
```

> ```
>  {
>   {{0.706, 0.688, 0.104}, 0.798},
>   {{0.001, 0.291, 0.744}, 0.349},
>   {{0.289, 0.718, 0.007}, 0.180},
>   {{0.759, 0.665, 0.346}, 0.631},
>   {{0.382, 0.219, 0.707}, 0.920},
>  }
> ```

now your interpolation function $f$ is defined by

```
f = Interpolation[Map[{Most[#], Last[#]} &, data], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Notice that `Interpolation` on *unstructured grids* is currently only supported for `InterpolationOrder->1`.